# Adding a File Field to my System.xml - File Not Uploading

Tags: module, magento-1, redirect, system.xml, dashboard

Here's my system.xml field definition:

```
<fields>
    <upload translate="label">
        <label>Upload Latest</label>
        <comment><![CDATA[This file gives you a more up-to-date BIN database. Please upload one regularly to stay ahead.]]></comment>
        <frontend_type>file</frontend_type>
        <backend_model>adminhtml/system_config_backend_file</backend_model>
        <upload_dir>var/uploads</upload_dir>
        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    </upload>
</fields>
```

The field shows successfully, but for some reason, when I browse for a file and click Save Config, it just redirects me to the Dashboard, there's no communication with any models, it literally just loads the dashboard.

How can I debug this issue successfully?

**Update**
After some additional digging, it appears to accept some files.

The particular file I'm looking to upload is a CSV that is 11.9 Mb. I've tried a small Jpg and it uploads successfully.

Could be to do with Filesize or File Type. How do I specifically enable CSV and increase the File Size limit to 20Mb?

Comment: This might be a php problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be very good to tell magento to allow upload only files with csv type.

In your extension create

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_System_Config_Backend_Csv extends Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Backend_File
{
    protected function _getAllowedExtensions()
    {
        return array('csv');
    }
}
```

Now in system.xml

```
<backend_model>namespace_module/system_config_backend_csv</backend_model>
```

And of course in `php.ini` increase `post_max_size` value.

```
post_max_size = 20M
```

Comment: it was the post_max_size that was causing it to drop out to the dashboard. Thanks for this; I've also taken your advice and added csv to the _getAllowedExtensions method.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem in magento.

Need to set in your configuration file.

In `php.ini` set

```
post_max_size = 20M
```